# Wordpress wp-admin Redirects to EC2 domain

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install my wordpress to AWS EC2.

1. I created my EC2 instance and send files to that. (and instance domain has ben blablabla.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com)
2. I used aws certificate manager for my domain.
3. I used cloudfront for using ssl certificate and; values are:
   origin: blablabla.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
   cnames: mysite.com

But when I connect to mysite.com/wp-admin it redirects me to blablabla.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

Yes, I tried to change siteurl and home variables. And it doesnt make any changes.

And other hand; when I try to connect with "mysite.com" it converts all files to http (buy when I try to connect wit blabla.eu... all files are https)

What should I make?

Answer (score 0):

Can be various things but I assume (based on previous experience) that some strings in Wordpress still contain mysite.com.

Before you go any further, it's worth to note that you can migrate your domain mysite.com to cloudfront/ec2/acm.

But if you want to just switch to another domain what I usually do is that I install wordpress CLI https://wp-cli.org/ and then I run `wp-cli search-replace mysite.com blablabla.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com --all-tables`. It's good to have a backup just in case something went wrong, but this worked for me multiple times without any issues.